# Increasing sequence of positive reals and an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $a_n>a_{n-1}> \cdots >a_1>a_0>0.$ Is it true that
$$
\eqalign{
&\lvert a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}z+\cdots+(n-1)a_1z^{n-2}+na_0z^{n-1} \rvert & \cr 
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 
< \lvert na_n+(n-1)a_{n-1}z+\cdots+a_1z^{n-1} \rvert 
}$$
for $|z| \leq 1?$

The result is obviously true for the case $n=1$.

Comment: Should it be $2 a_{n-2} z$ on the left-hand side?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us where the problem comes from? Why do you think that such an inequality might be true?

Comment: Because both separartely will lead to  the common  fact that all the zeros of $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_nz^n$ in $|z|<1.$